# Excel VBA: selecting cells base on variables

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to cycle through a row in my excel sheet. The row moves based on the data that is read into the sheet and the columns are variable and change based on the data. All the buttons are generated by another macro and when pressed enter their contents into the row I want to read from.
[image: For Example]

My Problem is that when I try to reference the cells with my variable I always get an error, no matter what I try. The most common error is a 'Type mismatch'

```
Sub Save()
Dim RowNum As Integer
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim answer As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

answer = MsgBox("Sind Sie sicher, dass Sie speichen möchten?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sind Sie sicher")
If answer = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Finds the location of the button ("Speichen Freigegebene Protokolle") is pressed in order to locate the desired row
RowNum = ws.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.row
'Finds how many columns there are with this data set
LastColumn = ws.Cells(11, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'cycles through columns of the row
For i = 7 To LastColumn
    Set MyRange = ws.Range(Cells(RowNum, i), Cells(RowNum + 1, i))

    If MyRange.Value = "Gut" Then  '##Type Mismatch error##
        'Save
    ElseIf MyRange.Value = "Einzelfreigeben" Then
        'Save
    ElseIf MyRange.Value = "Nacharbeit" Then
        'Dont Save
    ElseIf MyRange.Value = "Ausschuss" Then
        'Dont save
    ElseIf MyRange.Value = "" Then
        Err = MsgBox("Fehler! Sie haben eine Protokole zu pruefen vergessen.", vbOKOnly, "Fehler")
        Exit Sub
    End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: You are trying to get a single value from multiple cells.  Choose only the cell with the value. you will need to change this line `Set MyRange = ws.Range(Cells(RowNum, i), Cells(RowNum + 1, i))` so it only refers to one cell.  My guess is you want `Set MyRange = ws.Cells(RowNum + 1, i)`

Comment: You are trying to compare the value of a mult-cell range (which is an array) to a single value, and you can't do that with `=`. What is the purpose? Also, you need `ws` for the `Cells` calls too: `Set MyRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(RowNum, i), ws.Cells(RowNum + 1, i))`

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner and @Rory!!!! Referencing just the top cell has solved the problem. Thanks for the help, I didn't realise you only need to reference the top cell of a merged cell to get its contents.

Comment: Hello Sheds and welcome to the site.  We like to keep questions very to-the-point here, so I edited yours to trim it down.  Feel free to edit it again if you aren't happy with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer already provided by @Scott Craner and @Rory.

You can replace all your `If` and `ElseIf`s and use a `Select Case`, like the code below:

```
Select Case MyRange.Value
    Case "Gut"
        'Save
    Case "Einzelfreigeben"
        'Save
    Case "Nacharbeit"
        'Dont Save
    Case "Ausschuss"
        'Dont save
    Case ""
        Err = MsgBox("Fehler! Sie haben eine Protokole zu pruefen vergessen.", vbOKOnly, "Fehler")
        Exit Sub
End Select
```

Comment: This was not the solution that was provided.

Comment: @sheds141 I didn't say this was the solution, I said the solution was provided in the comments above by "Scott Craner" and "Rory". I suggested on top of that to replace your `If`s and `ElseIf`s to `Select Case` , you don't have to use this if you don't want to - it's up to you

Answer (score 0):

The answer already provided by @Scott Craner and @Rory.
It was as simple as just referencing only the top left cell of the merged cells instead of all cells in the merged cell.

```
    Set MyRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(RowNum, i), ws.Cells(RowNum, i))
```

Added the ws. before the `Cells()` was also a good tip to keep the code from changing sheets and workbooks.

Thanks all!